# Create a screen wide text field that wraps the text when displayed, not a long single line of text

Tags: visualforce

Here is the scenario: I am adding a single column text long field for product detail notes. So, when we double click the field a text box window opens. As we continue typing, when the text gets to the right edge of the text box the cursor drops down to the next line and continues to populate whatever we're typing, and so on with each line. However, when we click OK and the text is populated into the record, all of the text is a very long single line of text that runs off of the screen. I've run into this issue before and was told the only fix is to hit enter when you get near the right edge of the text box window, which works, but people never remember to hit enter and constantly complain about it.

I was told that Visualforce is a fix for this and that I can specify the text box width (i.e. 125 or 150 characters etc...) and that people can continue typing and the cursor will drop down a line, just like a Word doc, and when saved, the text will show on the screen exactly as it showed when they were typing.

Sorry for the lenghty details. Here are my questions: Is it true Visualforce has a fix and if so, (I'm an Apex idiot) how can I accomplish this? (Step by step please with the formula I need to write) and can it be added to an Opportunity record, not a separate Visualforce page? If so, how? Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say you added a "single column text long field" do you mean a "long text area" field? That sounds more like what you're describing and the kind of field you need to configure to display on your page.

Comment: Sorry about that. Yes, a long text area field in it's own section and the section is a single column so the field spans across the record.

Comment: Now that we have that cleared up, you'll get a much better answer to your question if you post your existing code that's not working for you. That will give us a reference point from which to help you sort out what's not working and why. You can use the edit button at the bottom left of your post to upate it with your code. After you paste it into your post, select it and click on the preformatted text icon `{}` before saving so it wil display properly.

Comment: I don't have any code at this point. The first and only thing I've tried is adding a long text field. When I double click the field a text box window opens. I write as much text as I need to and as I'm writing it looks fine, but when I click OK and look at it in the record it's just a single line of text that's a mile long. I'm trying to add something that is as wide as the record and the text shows up as it would in a Word doc rather than a really long single line. Someone told me Visualforce can accomplish this, but don't know anything about Visualforce.

Comment: text area (long) fields in the standard pagelayout UI only save a line break if the user actually enters a line break (Enter/Return key). None are synthesized.  In VF, ultimately, whatever is saved in the database has to have line breaks `\n` saved in the string. Either the user has to insert these or software has to insert these if you expect a subsequent display using reports or the standard layouts to show line breaks.

Comment: Thanks crop1645. I believe you clearly understand my query. So, if you don't mind, I have a couple of questions for clarification. You say "whatever is saved in the database has to have line breaks \n." By this do you mean that a developer can create a text box that is say wide enough for 150 characters of text and insert a line break, and then what will show on the screen is an empty text box that a user can type in, or are you saying that each user, say a sales person, will have to insert their own \n line breaks? If that's the case, the standard long text field may be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Text area (long) fields in the standard pagelayout UI only save a line break if the user actually enters a line break (Enter/Return key). None are synthesized.

In VF, ultimately, whatever is saved in the database has to have line breaks \n saved in the string. Either the user has to insert these or software has to insert these if you expect a subsequent display using reports or the standard layouts to show line breaks.

In answer to your question, triggers or VF code could initialize a text area(long) field with line breaks (`\n`) or for that matter, a set of line breaks with prefixed text:

`enter line 1 here:`

`\nenter line2 here:`

But the user can overtype all of this with backspace/delete keys so this is only 'hinting' to the user as to the format you want them to enter data